# Doctrine 2 Join an Entity which joins an Entity

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, left-join

I have an entity Rental which joins an entity Room and entity Room joins and entity Bed. How can I archive to load everything with one query? Actually with the following code the entity Bed will be loaded lazy. So I have even more than one query.

```
$qb->select('Rental', 'RentalRooms')
        ->from('Rental\Entity\Rental', 'Rental')           
        ->leftJoin('Rental.rooms', 'RentalRooms')          
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('Rental.slug', ':slug'))
        ->setParameter('slug', $slug);
```

I tried it this way:

```
$qb->select('Rental', 'RentalRooms', RentalBeds)
        ->from('Rental\Entity\Rental', 'Rental')           
        ->leftJoin('Rental.rooms', 'RentalRooms')
        ->leftJoin('RentalRooms.beds', 'RentalBeds')               
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('Rental.slug', ':slug'))
        ->setParameter('slug', $slug);
```

But than I get a Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 180 near 'RentalBeds WITH': Error: Class Rental\Entity\Rental has no association named beds".

And the exception is right, because the entity Rental has no association named beds. The room entity has the association named beds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! :D Just had to add ->addSelect('RentalBeds')

```
$qb->select('Rental', 'RentalRooms', RentalBeds)
    ->from('Rental\Entity\Rental', 'Rental')           
    ->leftJoin('Rental.rooms', 'RentalRooms')   
    ->leftJoin('RentalRooms.beds', 'RentalBeds')
    **->addSelect('RentalBeds')**           
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('Rental.slug', ':slug'))
    ->setParameter('slug', $slug);
```